# Extract the number of pages of PDFs recursively and dump them to a CSV

Tags: bash, find, csv, pdf, fd

I need to get a list of PDFs in various sub-folders of a directory structure and the number of pages of each PDF file. All saved into a CSV file, i.e. `<filename>,<number_of_pages>`.

I have used [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) and [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) to extract the number of pages recursively:

`fd ".pdf" --type f -x qpdf --show-npages {/}`

I tried to incorporate `echo` or `printf` in the command line to generate the CSV but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear in mind that I just installed `fd` so this is my first experience with it.

Since it did not work as I first expected, I picked a different approach and piped the output from `fd` into a Read-While loop and assign it to variables.

```
fd -e pdf -x echo {} | while read -r line; do 
    var1="$line" && var2=$(qpdf --show-npages "$line"); 
    echo "var1,var2" > myfile.csv;
done
```

I should note that I have not RTFM-ed as well. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Apart the odd `done` at the end of the loop and the usual double quotes to take into account PDF filenames with spaces, your solution was spot on! my updated version: `fd -e pdf -x echo {} | while read -r line; do var1=$line && var2=$(qpdf --show-npages "$line"); echo "$var1,$var2" >> myfile.csv; done`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I always forget to finish the loop. ;) Would the downvoters also elaborate on why they are in disagreement? I would like to learn the reason.

Comment: @fragamemnon: I haven't downvoted your answer, but @Marco has already improved it a bit and fixed a glaring error (though not yet optimal). Here's my suggestion: ***`fd -e pdf -x echo {} | while read -r line; do var=$(qpdf --show-npages "$line"); echo "\"$line\",\"$var\"" >> myfile.csv; done`***. This will put each field into quotes inside the CSV.